# Proof of the five lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

How to do this using the snake lemma? this is an exercise in Lang's Algebra book. It should somehow be obvious, but I don't see it

Comment: I think usually they are proven independently.

Comment: @OOO I guess you're right; I must have been thinking about something else.

Comment: You can easily do the *short* five lemma with the snake lemma

Comment: But the short one is trivial, I have done it here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581698/on-a-commutative-diagram/596779#596779

Comment: @ooo: It doesn't hold for longer diagrams. The spectral sequence of the corresponding double complex will give you some associated exact sequences, though.

Comment: I didn't want to say that spectral sequences are "the" appropriate tool here, but rather wanted to inform you how to correct your statement (which you have deleted meanwhile, so that my comment doesn't make any sense anymore, thanks).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The usual five lemma follows from the short five lemma: factor each morphism appearing in the rows into an epimorphism followed by a monomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof can be found in Bourbaki's Algèbre homologique, §1, Cor. 3.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}$
(The five lemma)

Consider a commutative diagram of $R$-modules and homomorphisms such that each row is exact:

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
M_1 @>\alpha_1>>M_2 @>\alpha_2>> M_3 @>\alpha_3>> M_4 @>\alpha_4>> M_5\\
@Vf_1VV @Vf_2VV @Vf_3VV @Vf_4VV @Vf_5VV\\
N_1 @>\beta_1>>N_2 @>\beta_2>> N_3 @>\beta_3>> N_4 @>\beta_4>> N_5\\
\end{CD}$$
Prove:

(a) If $f_1$ is surjective and $f_2,f_4$ are monomorphisms, then $f_3$ is a monomorphism.

(b) If $f_5$ is a monomorphism and $f_2,f_4$ are surjective, then $f_3$ is surjective.

Proof:

(a) First, we consider the following snake diagram:

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
@. M_1 @>\alpha_1>> M_2 @>\alpha_2>> \mathrm{Im}\alpha_2 @>>> 0 \\
@. @VV\pi_1\circ f_1V @VVf_2V @VVf_3|_{\mathrm{Im}\alpha_2}V @. \\
0 @>>>N_1/\ker\beta_1 @>\tilde{\beta_1}>>N_2 @>\beta_2>> N_3  @. \\
\end{CD}$$

where $\pi_i:N_i\rightarrow N_i/\ker\beta_i$ is the natural quotient map, and $\tilde{\beta}_i:N_i/\ker\beta_i\rightarrow N_{i+1}$ is the injective homomorphism induced by $\beta_i$. By snake lemma we have the following exact sequence:
$$ \ker \pi_1\circ f_1\rightarrow \underbrace{\ker f_2}_{=0}\rightarrow \ker f_3|_{\mathrm{Im}\alpha_2}\rightarrow \underbrace{\coker \pi_1\circ f_1}_{=0}\rightarrow \coker f_2\rightarrow \coker f_3|_{\mathrm{Im}\alpha_2}$$
Hence $\ker f_3|_{\mathrm{Im}\alpha_2}=0$.

Now, we consider another snake diagram:

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
0@>>> \mathrm{Im}(\alpha_2) @>i>> M_3 @>\alpha_3>> \mathrm{Im}\alpha_3 @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVf_3|_{\mathrm{Im}\alpha_2}V @VVf_3V @VVf_4|_{\mathrm{Im}\alpha_3}V @. \\
0 @>>>\mathrm{Im}\beta_2 @>i>>N_3 @>\beta_3>> N_4  @. \\
\end{CD}$$

Note: To draw this diagram, we implicitly used $f_3(\mathrm{Im}(\alpha_2))\subseteq \mathrm{Im}(\beta_2)$. This is because $f_3\circ \alpha_2=\beta_2\circ f_2$.

By snake lemma, we have the following exact sequence:
$$ \underbrace{\ker f_3|_{\mathrm{Im}\alpha_2}}_{=0}\rightarrow \ker f_3\rightarrow \underbrace{\ker f_4|_{\mathrm{Im}\alpha_3}}_{=0}\rightarrow \dots$$
we deduce that $\ker f_3=0$.

(b) First, we consider the following snake diagram:

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
@. M_3 @>\alpha_3>> M_4 @>\alpha_4>> \mathrm{Im}\alpha_4 @>>> 0 \\
@. @VV\pi_3\circ f_3V @VVf_4V @VVf_5|_{\mathrm{Im}\alpha_4}V @. \\
0 @>>>N_3/\ker\beta_3 @>\tilde{\beta_3}>>N_4 @>\beta_4>> N_5  @. \\
\end{CD}$$
and the following exact sequence:

$$ \ker \pi_3\circ f_3\rightarrow \ker f_4\rightarrow \underbrace{\ker f_5|_{\mathrm{Im}\alpha_4}}_{=0}\rightarrow \coker \pi_3\circ f_3\rightarrow \underbrace{\coker f_4}_{=0}\rightarrow \coker f_5|_{\mathrm{Im}\alpha_4}$$
Hence $\coker \pi_3\circ f_3=0$.

Now, we consider another snake diagram:

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
@. M_2 @>\alpha_2>> M_3 @>\gamma_3>> M_3/\ker \alpha_3 @>>> 0 \\
@. @VV\pi_2\circ f_2V @VVf_3V @VV\widetilde{\pi_3\circ f_3}V @. \\
0 @>>>N_2/\ker\beta_2 @>\tilde{\beta_2}>>N_3 @>\pi_3>> N_3/\ker \beta_3  @>>>0 \\
\end{CD}$$
Note: To draw this diagram, we implicitly used $\ker \alpha_3\subseteq \ker (\pi_3\circ f_3)$. To show this, suppose $\alpha_3(x)=0$, then
$$0=f_4(\alpha_3(x))=\beta_3(f_3(x))\Rightarrow f_3(x)\in \ker\beta_3\Rightarrow x\in \ker (\pi_3\circ f_3)$$

By snake lemma, we have the following exact sequence:
$$ \dots\rightarrow \underbrace{\coker \pi_2\circ f_2}_{=0}\rightarrow \coker f_3\rightarrow \underbrace{\coker \widetilde{\pi_3\circ f_3}}_{=\coker \pi_3\circ f_3=0}$$
hence $\coker f_3=0$.

Comment: I am a newer to Mathexchange. I wonder why the commutative diagrams cannot be displayed?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2324/42781 for commutative diagram help.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Thanks, I got it.